# Office 365 Sharing.js

Tags: javascript, office-365, office-365-developer

I want to share my site to external users, and so, I thought that i would use sharing.js and exeutethis function on button click :
`EnsureScriptFunc('sharing.js', 'DisplaySharingDialog', function(){DisplaySharingDialog('mySiteURL')});`

my question is how can i specify the default group and don't let the user choose it(if possible) and how can I execute a custom js code after that.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally drop the sharing.js and instead used this :

```
var options = 
{
title: "Add External User",
url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_layouts/15/aclinv.aspx?GroupId=" + currGroupID,
dialogReturnValueCallback: setUserData
};
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

and that's working.

N.B: the user could not be retireved until he use the link on the sended mail to connect.